# How do I stop Form Builder/API from filtering certain HTML tags from #prefix and #suffix on fields?

Tags: 8, forms

### **Summary:**

Drupal seems to be stripping certain html tags from the #suffix of Form API created fields and I can't figure out how to stop it.

### **Environment:**

Working in Drupal 8.9.13 with a minimum of modules.

### **Details:**

I don't know Drupal well, and I've been tasked with fixing a custom Form that was imported from Drupal 7. It's being built through the Form API stuff, i.e. https://www.drupal.org/node/268072
The form is using #prefix and #suffix to wrap a div around each field, but it's also adding several labels to the #suffix that are being used for validation notices (shown and hidden via jQuery). Unor

I can embed as many divs as I want in the #suffix, but it's stripping labels. I also tried spans, and those seem to be stripped too.
`'#suffix' => '<div class="bupkis"><label>vegetable</label>cabbage</div></div>'),`
is resulting in `<div class="bupkis">vegetablecabbage</div></div>`

I appreciate that this isn't probably the ideal way to manage validation, but it's what I have and it was working in Drupal 7. I don't have budget to rebuild it all, I just want to get it to work as-is in Drupal 8.

### **Attempted fixes:**

I've tried adding label and span to the 'Filtered HTML' format, in case it was using that as a default, but it didn't help.

I've tried Markup::create, i.e.
`'#suffix' => Markup::create('<div class="bupkis"><label>vegetable</label>cabbage</div></div>'),` which I found in another stack overflow post... but that just causes a crash.

I've tried to find like a content type or something for this form, to see if I can adjust filters there... but there doesn't seem to be one. I think it's just dynamically generated, and there's no underlying pre-set structure?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/form-api/form-render-elements says it will be filtered for XSS safety... not sure if that includes <label>

Comment: *Just causes a crash* ... probably a missing `use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;`

Comment: @4k4 Can you throw that as a full answer? You were absolutely right, and having the right Use statement and then using Markup::create, it works! I'd love to give you credit for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The filtering doesn't use a text filter format. It is filtered against [Xss::$adminTags](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Xss.php/property/Xss%3A%3AadminTags/9.2.x), which doesn't contain `<label>`.

If you are sure the string is safe you can put it in a [Markup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Markup.php/class/Markup/9.2.x) object to avoid XSS filtering:

```
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;

...

  '#suffix' => Markup::create('<div class="bupkis"><label>vegetable</label>cabbage</div></div>'),
```

For this to work you have to add a use statement before the class or procedural function.

Comment: Thank you so much once again!